# I want to merge the second query with the first and show the product media and category media as a URL in MY SQL Magento 2

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
SELECT catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value.entity_id as product_id,
IF(media_type = 'external-video', "video", "image") as type, 
CASE 
    WHEN media_type = "external-video" 
    THEN (SELECT
    url
  FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video` 
   JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`
  on catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value.value_id = catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video.value_id LIMIT 1)
    WHEN media_type = "image" THEN value
END AS url 
from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value 
JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery 
ON catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value.value_id = catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value_id


SELECT catalog_category_entity.entity_id as category_id,
value as url
from catalog_category_entity 
JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar 
ON catalog_category_entity.entity_id = catalog_category_entity_varchar.entity_id
WHERE `attribute_id` = '48'
```

Here I fetch product media in the First query and fetch category media in the second query
I want to merge the second query with the first and show the product media and category media as a URL

Comment: are the url from the first identical to the second?

Comment: yes both have the different values

Comment: to join two rsultset you need a bindung column where you can use `ON a.url = b.url` if they are different you need aniother column that bind both

Comment: But how can I achieve this because in my first query table A & table B join and in my second query table C & table D join

Comment: that is a point that i can't tell you. look  at the tables and try to find one combining column, or use row_number or such a syntetic column